# BigQuery Equivalent of Merge Statement

Tags: google-bigquery, merge-statement, bigquery-udf

I am performing migration from teradata to Big query. I have encountered a merge statement having VALUES in USING clause.

```
MERGE INTO department DL
                        USING VALUES
                        (
                        2,'ABC'
                        ) AS V 
                        (Run_Id, Country) 
                          ON DL.department_id = V.Run_Id
                        WHEN MATCHED THEN
                          UPDATE SET 
                            department_description = V.country
                        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                          INSERT
                          (
                          V.Run_Id
                          , V.Country
                          curr
                          );
```

Can anyone help me out in finding what would be its BigQuery equivalent.

Comment: BigQuery has `MERGE`: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ***MERGE*** statement is used when you want to updated a `target table` using a `source table` with one or more primary keys(PK).

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/dw2bq/td2bq/td-bq-sql-translation-reference-tables#merge_statement), the differences between Teradata's and BigQuery's MERGE are:

> Teradata's MERGE operation is limited to matching primary keys within
> one access module processor (AMP). In contrast, BigQuery has no size
> or column limitation for MERGE operations, therefore using MERGE is a
> useful optimization. However, if the MERGE is primarily a large
> delete, see optimizations for DELETE elsewhere in this document.
>
> DML scripts in BigQuery have slightly different consistency semantics
> than equivalent statements in Teradata. For example, Teradata's SET
> tables in session mode might ignore duplicates during a MERGE
> operation. For an overview on handling MULTISET and SET tables,
> snapshot isolation, and session and transaction handling, see the
> CREATE INDEX section elsewhere in this document.

In your case, it seems you are using the *PK* as `DL.department_id` and `V.Run_Id`. Although, within your syntax inside the ***USING*** clause you should specify the targeted table not only its fields. Below is the syntax, [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement):

```
MERGE target_name [[AS] alias]
USING source_name
ON merge_condition
#WHEN MATCHED 
#WHEN NOT MATCHED
```

Therefore, in your case, the syntax will be:

```
MERGE dataset.department DL
USING (SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset.source_table`) V
ON DL.department_id = V.Run_Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET DL.department_description = V.country
WHEN NOT MATCHED
#first specify the name of the columns in your then the values to insert
INSERT(colum1, column2, column3) VALUES(V.Run_Id, V.Country, V.curr)
```

Notice that within the `INSERT` clause you first specify the columns that data will be added then inside `VALUES` the values to be inserted, you can write the values explicitly or name the columns from your `source_table` with the data to be added. I would like to point that, I considered `curr` as a column from your source table. Also, you did not stated your source table, only some of its fields.

For further clarification, below is another example

```
MERGE `dataset.target_table` T
USING (SELECT "New value" as value, "1" as ID) S
ON T.ID = S.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T.value_column = S.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(value_column, id) VALUES("Value added", s.ID)
```

Again, pay attention to the `INSERT` clause, first the columns from the target table are described then the values which will be inserted in the table `WHEN NOT MATCHED`.

Comment: Thanks, Alex for your help I have also converted the USING clause into subquery and it solves my problem